# How to change separator for decimal and thousands in numbers in Excel C #?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program in C # to change the format of found numbers in an Excel file with

1234,456 at 1,234.456;

23456,3 by 23,456.3;

5243,345 in 5,243.345  etc.

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in exDocument.Worksheets) {
    Excel.Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
    Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", last);
    int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
    int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= lastUsedColumn; rowIndex++) {

        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= lastUsedRow; columnIndex++) {
            if (range.Cells[columnIndex, rowIndex].value2 != null) {
                string myString = ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[columnIndex, rowIndex]).Value2.ToString();
                range.Cells[columnIndex, rowIndex] = FormatNumber(myString);
                Console.WriteLine(range.Cells[columnIndex, rowIndex]);
                // object missingVal = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                // Excel.Range match = range.Cells[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value2.ToString().Find("<[0-9]@,[0-9]@>", missingVal, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                //     Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, missingVal, missingVal);
                //strok.Find.text= "<[0-9]@,[0-9]@>";
            }
        }
    }
}

private static string FormatNumber(string text) {
    if (double.TryParse(text, out double number)) {
        return number.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
        // Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Number dont change and In console i see.

```
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
System.__ComObject
```

Please tell me how to correctly convert the found numbers to the desired format.

Comment: Have you tried the _Application.ThousandsSeparator Property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.thousandsseparator?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Application_ThousandsSeparator

Comment: can you give an example how to use?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this method can work.

```
    private static string FormatNumber(string text)
    {
       text=  text.Replace(',', '.');
        double number;
        if (double.TryParse(text, out number))
        {
             string result = String.Format("{0:N}", number);
           
            return result; 
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But dont work. Removes the decimal part.

Comment: Hm...and veru strange...Changes occur only on 1 sheet, but sheets are listed

Comment: well, I have tested it with the samples you've provided. Works with me. Strange!

Comment: @Muhammad Idrees i find mistake. Some cells have a numeric format, not a general one, and when found, the integer part is simply zeroed. Tell me how to change the cell format to the GENERAL format

Comment: Can you specify the inputs and their correct outcomes?